# how do I sort the output of 'locate' by file modification time

Tags: linux, unix, locate

When I use the `locate` command, I often wish that the output was sorted in reverse chronological order, just like with `ls -rtc`. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I realized that this answer is relevant: http://superuser.com/a/251432/576570

However, it seems one should pass `--full-time` to `ls` in order to get a field which is sortable (as well as `-d` so you don't list directories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to pipe your list of files through a sequence of commands:

```
locate your-search-term |
  xargs stat --printf '%.Y\t%n\n' |
  sort -n -r |
  cut -f 2-
```

The first line locates your files — you know this already. The second line `stat`-s a file and prints the last modification time (epoch seconds) and the file path, for each located filename. The third line sorts the lines numerically descending. The last line cuts the modification time and the separator from each line, leaving the original path.

Comment: Thank you, I'll put this in a little script in my home directory. I didn't know about `stat` before. By the way, I use `locate -0` and `xargs -0` so that filenames with spaces come out OK.

Comment: That's a good practice (i.e. NIL-separated paths) when you expect whitespace in the paths. Esp. newlines can be troublesome here, they will destroy `sort` (which can be overcome by adding `-z` switch) and `cut` (which may be overcome by replacing `cut` with `perl -p0e 's/^\S*\s+//'`)

Comment: I created a script called `time-sort-files` with contents:

`tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 stat --printf '%.Z\t%z\t%n\0' | sort -zn | cut -z -f 2- | tr '\0' '\n' | sed 's/:..\..*\t/\t/'`

It also prints dates next to each file. The initial `tr` makes it so I can pipe an ordinary newline-separated file list into `time-sort-files`. The `sort` lacks `-r` because I actually wanted chronological order (I said "reverse" by mistake!), like `ls -rt`. Thanks again!